# Cross compiling libtorrent for raspberry pi 3 model B

Tags: c++, boost, libtorrent, boost-build, libtorrent-rasterbar

I've been trying to cross compile [jlibtorrent](https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire-jlibtorrent/) for the raspberry pi which uses [boost build](https://github.com/boostorg/build) for compiling. I am using [the officially provided cross compiler](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) with the following `config.jam`:

```
import os ;

using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ :
    <cxxflags>-fPIC
    <cxxflags>-std=c++14
    <cxxflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
    <cxxflags>-fvisibility=hidden
    <linkflags>-m32
    <linkflags>-static-libstdc++
    <linkflags>-static-libgcc
    <linkflags>"-z noexecstack"
    # debug information
    <cxxflags>-g
    <cxxflags>-gdwarf-4
    <cxxflags>-ggdb
    ;
```

I basically copied the existing configuration for linux-x86 and replaced the compiler, but I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
libtorrent/src/entry.cpp: In member function 'libtorrent::entry& libtorrent::entry::operator[](libtorrent::string_view)':
libtorrent/src/entry.cpp:86:33: error: no matching function for call to 
'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, libtorrent::entry, libtorrent::aux::strview_less, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, libtorrent::entry> > >::find(libtorrent::string_view&)' 

auto const i = dict().find(key);
```

My only guess is that the version of the cross compiler (4.9.3) is not compatible with libtorrent, because I saw in the linux-32-config.jam that it uses g++-5. Is there anything else I am missing?
You can find the modified repository [in my github repositories](https://github.com/mreilaender/frostwire-jlibtorrent). I am using [`swig/build-linux-armv7.sh`](https://github.com/mreilaender/frostwire-jlibtorrent/blob/master/swig/build-linux-armv7.sh) for building.

Comment: as a somewhat unrelated note. a Jamfile toolset isn't meant to include the c++ version, -fPIC, -g and -static-*. you can control that on the b2 command line with: debug-symbols=on runtime-link=static cxxstd=14. Also, libtorrent honors C++ aliasing rules, so it's technically not necessary to disable them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Arvid I managed to compile it using the current stable branch for libtorrent (RC_1_2) and the following jam file, which you can find [here](https://github.com/mreilaender/frostwire-jlibtorrent/blob/master/swig/config/linux-arm-config.jam).

```
import os ;

using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ :
    <cxxflags>-fPIC
    <cxxflags>-std=c++11
    <cxxflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
    <cxxflags>-fvisibility=hidden
    <linkflags>-static-libstdc++
    <linkflags>-static-libgcc
    <linkflags>"-z noexecstack"
    # debug information
    <cxxflags>-g
    <cxxflags>-gdwarf-4
    <cxxflags>-ggdb;
```

Answer (score 1):

that call (std::map::find()) was added in C++14 (see [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)). I see you pass in `-std=c++14` on the command line as well. Are you sure your GCC supports C++14? It seems a bit old for that.

The current stable branch of libtorrent only requires C++11 support, if that is the branch you're building, there may be something wrong with the compiler support detection [here](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/RC_1_2/include/libtorrent/entry.hpp#L90). If you are building from libtorrent `master`, it requires proper C++14 support. So in that case you may want to use the stable release.

Comment: I changed `-std=c++14` as well as removed the `<linkflags>-m32` and build from the current stable branch (RC_1_2 i guess?) and it does indeed compile now. Thank you very much :)